# merging of search forms

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 search forms. One is linked to my local db of records and the other one links through an API to another db.

I want to now when my db does not have the required record, have it use the second search form without the user needing to insert the data again.

Is this possible and how do I go about merging the two?

Thanks for all the help guys.

Combination of form functions:

```
<div class="article">
      <h2>    
      <br> 
      SEARCH A REFERENCE
      <br> 
       </h2>
    </center>

    <body>
    <div id="formsearch">
    <br> 
       <form method="post" action="" name="form1" id="form1" >   

     Enter the  ID Number 
     <br><br>
     <b>Search Record  </b> <input type="text" name="term" /><br />
     <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="btn" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <h3> <center> Search Result (s) </h3> 
 <?php

if ($_REQUEST['submit']) {

$term = $_POST['term'];

$row ['employerid'] == $user_data ['user_id'];
$XX = "<br><br><div class='messagebox'><h2> <center> Oops! </h2> <p>We were only to retrieve a partial record on <strong>$term</strong>  you have entered. Please make use of our contact form if you would like us to get you your reference. Be sure to enter the three required fields.  <a href='Mailforms/refrequest.php'  class='lightbox'>Click Here!</a> or to validate the id <a href='idverification.php'> Click here</a></p>
<br />
</div>";  
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT idnumber,
firstname,
lastname,
companyname,
jobtitle,
dismissal,
terminationdate,
startdate,
CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,startdate,terminationdate), ' years and ', 
MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,startdate,terminationdate),12), ' months ') AS time_diff
FROM ref_employees
WHERE idnumber= '$term'")
   or die('Error in query : $sql. ' .mysql_error());


if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0  )  {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    if ($row ['employed'] == '1') {
    echo '<h4>Currently Employed By :   '.$row['companyname'];
    echo '</h4> ';
    echo '<a href="#">Any doubts? Enquire about this candidate</a> ';
    }

    if ($row ['employed'] == '0') {
        echo ' <h4>Some Available Options For:</h4>';
        include 'includes/admenu.php';
    echo '<h4>Not Currently employed    '.$row['companyname'];
    echo '</h4> ';

    }

     echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>ID Number</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th><th>company</th> <th>Job Title</th> <th>Period</th><th>Reason for dismissal</th><th></th><th></th></tr>";
   echo "<tr>";
             echo '<td>' . $row['idnumber'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['companyname'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['jobtitle'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' .($row['startdate'] + $row['terminationdate']).'</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['dismissal'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="editemp.php?idnumber=' . $row['idnumber'] . '">Achievements</a></td>';
                echo '<td><a href="delete.php?idnumber=' . $row['idnumber'] . '">training</a></td>';
                echo "</tr>"; 
        } 

        // close table>
        echo "</table>";



}
}
else
 {
$id_number = $_POST['term'];

$authenticate = authentication();

$login_message = $authenticate['error_code'];
$session_id = $authenticate['session_id'];


$id_verification = verify_id($session_id, $id_number);
}


if (!empty($id_verification)){
echo '<br/>';
echo '<h3>Search Information</h3>';
echo 'Time Stamp: ';
echo $id_verification['TIME_STAMP'];
echo 'SOAP Result: ';
echo $id_verification['LOGIN-MESSAGE'];
echo ' ';
echo $id_verification['SEARCH-MESSAGE'];
echo ' ';
echo $id_verification['SEARCH-RESULT'];
echo '<br/>';
echo '<h3>Data: </h3>';
echo '<br/>ID Number: ';
echo $id_verification['IDNUMBER'];
echo '<br/>First Names: ';
echo $id_verification['FIRSTNAMES'];
echo '<br/>Last Name: ';
echo $id_verification['SURNAME'];

echo '<br/>Birthday: ';
echo $id_verification['BIRTHDAY'];
echo '<br/>Age: ';
echo $id_verification['AGE'];
echo '<br/>Gender: ';
echo $id_verification['GENDER'];
echo '<br/>Citizen: ';
echo $id_verification['CITIZEN'];
echo '<br/>Death Status: ';
echo $id_verification['DEATH-STATUS'];
echo '<br/>Death Date: ';
echo $id_verification['DEATH-DATE'];
echo '<br/>Death Place: ';
echo $id_verification['DEATH-PLACE'];

unset($_SESSION['id_verification']);


}
mysql_free_result($sql);
mysql_close($connection);


?>
```

Comment: I have provided the code

Comment: In your local search form you are checking for the number of results in `if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0  )  {`. I would suggest to put an else statement and execute the API search. `if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0  )  { /* local search goes here */ } else { /* put api search here */ }` In fact this is what Nesarajan suggested.

Comment: I combined the 2 but no luck. Please I would really apreciat you assistance with this, I am new to php.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Btw. you should always escape user generated query parameters and use the MySQLi extension instead of mysql_* as they are deprecated since PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send both search form into one location.

First you need to search into local if not again search it in API. Mean you need to do the search in single server file.

Hope this clear else post me in detail.